# Certain values give incorrect results for prime number checking function

Tags: c

I recently wrote a program in C for a calculator. To produce a function that checks if the user input is a prime number or not (amongst other functions).

I essentially used this code (excluding all other functions):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int testForPrime(int);

int main(void) {

    int ioperand1 = 0;
    printf("\nEnter the value to check if prime (positive integer): ");
    scanf("%d", &ioperand1);
    if (testForPrime(ioperand1) != 0)
        printf("\nThis number is prime.\n");
    else
        printf("\nThis number is not prime.\n");
    return 0;
}

int testForPrime(int operand1) {

    int i = 0;
    for (i = 2; i <= sqrt(operand1); i++) {
        if (operand1 == 0 || operand1 == 1)
            return 0;
        else if (operand1 % i == 0) 
            return 0;
        else
            return 1; 
    }
}
```

^
This code above produces the errors

I am not sure why the code produces an error for the value 9 (I fixed that above by adding the condition: if (operand1 == 9), but I don't understand why 9 is seemingly the only value that results in an incorrect solution (It would say 9 was prime, but not any other number give an incorrect result).

One other bug that I remidied with an extra condition statement was the value of 2.
Before adding the extra conditional statement in the main function: if (ioperand1 == 2), the value 2 would always come up as a non prime number.
I originally found this solution to check for prime numbers online, and I still don't understand why the for loop starts from 2.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int testForPrime(int);

int main(void) {

    int ioperand1 = 0;
    printf("\nEnter the value to check if prime (positive integer): ");
    scanf("%d", &ioperand1);
    if (testForPrime(ioperand1) != 0 || ioperand1 == 2)
        printf("\nThis number is prime.\n");
    else
        printf("\nThis number is not prime.\n");
    return 0;
}

int testForPrime(int operand1) {

    int i = 0;
    for (i = 2; i <= sqrt(operand1); i++) {
        if (operand1 == 0 || operand1 == 1 || operand1 == 9)
            return 0;
        else if (operand1 % i == 0) 
            return 0;
        else
            return 1; 
    }
}
```

^This code above fixed the problem, though I don't undesttand why the problem existed in the first place.

TL;DR:
I don't know why this code doesn't work without the extra conditional statements:
if (operand1 == 9) in function definition,
and
if (ioperand1 == 2) in main function.

If anyone could help clear this up, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because your prime checking loop does not iterate. It always returns on the first iteration. It must run to completion, and *then* the number will be prime. So

```
int testForPrime(int operand1) {
    if(operand1 < 2) {
        return 0;
    }
    int sr = (int)round(sqrt(operand1));
    for(int i = 2; i <= sr; i++) {
        if (operand1 % i == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: You can halve the execution time by adding `if(operand1 % 2 == 0) { return 0; }` which eliminates all even numbers, and then step by 2 with `for(int i = 3; i <= sr; i += 2)` which checks only odd divisors.

Comment: Be careful -- doing (just) that will incorrectly return false for operand1 == 2 (which is prime).  You could instead use `if (operand1 % 2 == 0) return operand1 == 2;`

Comment: @ChrisDodd yes, that was definitely an oversight, thank you.